# Question concerning a minimal faithful left ideal in an artin algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, homological-algebra, idempotents

Let $B$ be an artin algebra an suppose there is a faithful projective-injective left $B$-module. Moreover, there is a minimal faithful left ideal $Be$ for some idempotent $e\in B$.

1) What does minimal mean? Minimal with respect to what?

2) Does $Be$ have to be indecomposable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "moreover"? Assume moreover that there is such an ideal? Since you say this after several hypotheses, it sounds maybe like you want it to be a consequence of those hypotheses (but the wording disguises that.) It would be good to give the source of this problem, or better yet a link to somewhere we can read it in print.

Comment: It concerns Theorem 2.10 in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002186930098726X#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Apparently, "minimal faithful" is meant to mean "minimal among faithful ideals." Let $R$ be some interesting commutative quasi-Frobenius ring (say, $\Bbb Z/(36)$ ). In such a ring, nontrivial ideals have nontrivial annihilators due to the double-annihilator property. This means that the entire ring is a minimal faithful ideal (actually, *the* minimum faithful ideal) of the ring.
2. Moreover, the same ring is a faithful projective-injective module over itself, but it is not an irreducible module.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!